# Function plots - objective comparison for choosing between tikz data-visualisation and pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, tikz-datavisualization

I am writing my PhD thesis now, and want to plot some results (mainly the evolution of various simulation quantities on y-axis against time on the x-axis). I estimate to have around 50 such plots in my full thesis.

In the past, I have used `tikz`  for scientific-illustrations (ie. artwork), not for a plot of `f(t) vs t`. But I cannot remember the `tikz` syntax now, although I can  jog my memory given a couple of hours time.

For this task of function-plotting, in the tikz manual, there is an entire part (Part VI) devoted to data visualization. I also came across the `pgfplots` package which also uses PGF/Tikz as its base.

I understand the importance of having choices. So, I absolutely understand the goals and existence of the `asympotote`,`metapost/metafun`, `pstricks`-family and `gnuplottex`  libraries/engines. Each serve a different target audience.

But once a user has decided to use the `pgf` engine for their graphics, isn't the effort better concentrated on a single choice and avoid duplication in efforts?

Personally, the real question (for me) is:

> I probably have the time to learn just *one* package. Is there an objective comparison between `pgfplots` and `tikz data visualization`, i.e. the benefits and demerits of using one versus the other?

PS to moderators: I'd like this to be a community-wiki if possible, since lots of newcomers can benefit from an objective analysis of these packages to make an informed choice before diving into either.

Comment: My opinion: take pgfplots. According to what I understand, this is an "extension" of `data visualization`. That is, most of the things you can do with `data visualization` you can also do with `pgfplots`, but the converse is not true.

Comment: @marmot  It would be beneficial if you can provide more details or a list of "things you can do with ```pgfplots``` and not vice versa".  Even if you start a small list in an answer, the moderators and other experienced users can add to it.

Comment: @marmot, as far as I know first was TikZ without the `data visualization` library, than came `pgfplots` and I think with `tikz` v3 the `data visualization` library was added ... And thus these are "competing" packages to plot data.

Comment: @StefanPinnow Yes. I noticed that too, having looked at an old version of the manual. I wonder what good can result from that? It just leads to fragmentation. Two solutions using the same ```pgf``` engine, when the efforts can be concentrated on making a single one even better.  That said, is there a comparison, maybe on "ease of use, capabilities etc."?

Comment: And I think because you have the extremely good `pgfplots` package which was available years before the `data visualization` library, that is why -- most likely -- not that much people use the later, although it might be -- in principle -- as good as `pgfplots` (I never used the libary). This is supported by the number of questions asked here on TeX.SX. While there are only 54 questions tagged with [tag:tikz-datavisualization] there are 6025 tagged with [tag:pgfplots].

Comment: @StefanPinnow Thank you. Yes, and those questions are on specific problems faced by individual users on those libraries.  There is no overarching question that compares these two on their relative strengths and weaknesses. It would be great if someone with experience to these packages can provide a comparison.

Comment: I agree that now there is a bit of fragmentation. But as far as I know Till Tantau decided to (just) create the `data visualization` library and Christian Feuersänger (the author of `pgfplots`) didn't know that either until the release ...

Comment: If you scroll through the part in the TikZ manual about the `datavisualization` library, and compare that to the table of of contents for `pgfplots`, one thing at least is obvious: `pgfplots` (currently) has support for a much wider variety of plots. `datavisualization` does not do for example, bar plots, comb plots and box plots.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. This is exactly the kind of comparisons that could be beneficial. Can you maybe consider posting this as an answer?

Comment: @StefanPinnow That is also strange. Dr Christian Feuersänger is a strong contributor to ```tikz``` itself, and I think he wrote large parts of that mammoth manual.

Comment: I think that this isn't a useful way to phrase the question. If you specified some requirements perhaps they are met by pgfplots, or by pstricks or metapost,  pre-restricting to the _back end_  drawing library seems a strange place to start.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, understood this. My post is more along the lines typical of a community-wiki, rather than a specific question. I think we have plenty of questions about issues and usage of both packages. This is intended as an umbrella question or a meta-question asking for comparisons.

Comment: @Krishna, that's right, but I guess most of that he already had written before the release of v3.

Comment: @StefanPinnow I see. However, Tantau seems to be aware about the existence of the ```pgfplots``` library. In Section 22 (plots of functions), he says: _"A warning before we get started: If you are looking for an easy way to create a normal plot of a function with
scientific axes, ignore this section and instead look at the pgfplots package or at the datavisualization commad from Part V1"_

Comment: Sure he did. I just stated the other way round, i.e. Christian didn't know that Till is doing something similar.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, the `datavisualization` library can currently handle only two types of plots: line plots and scatter plots. If you want any other type of plot, you need to create your own "visualizer". The manual does describe how to do that, but I suspect most users wouldn't want to.

`pgfplots` on the other hand can also make things like bar plots, histograms, box plots, comb plots, area plots and quiver plots. So `pgfplots` currently has a wider range of plot types supported.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would take `pgfplots`, which is, of course based on Ti*k*Z. Simple argument: pgfplots has over 500 pages of documentation whereas the data the data visualization part of the `pgfmanual` "only" less than 120. This already suggests that it is mightier. But it is probably an illusion to assume that you'll get away with "only" reading the `pgfplots` manual if you want to really use the package. So far I have not seen any feature of `data visualization` that cannot be achieved with `pgfplots`. On the other hand, things like `\addplot3` seem not to be available in `data visualization`, nor all the nice features involving tables.

Note that this is only a personal assessment.

Comment: thank you for your answer, especially the point about ```addplot3```. I shall wait to see if more aspects of comparison will be provided by others.

Comment: Flip-side: You may (I do) prefer the data-visualisation syntax to that of `pgfplots`. If it does what you need, it's simpler - partly because there are 400-odd fewer pages to hunt through. The `pgfplots` manual is overwhelming. It takes me forever to find what I need and what I need is usually scattered in different parts of the manual. If you need `pgfplots`, you need it. But if you don't, why deal with the extra complexity? Can `pgfplots` use external helpers in the same way as Ti*k*Z (e.g. `gnuplot`).  @Krishna

Comment: @cfr If you are asking whether pgfplots can use external programs such as `gnuplot` the answer is yes.