# Making a Plot: Pgfplot or Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-datavisualization

I find two possible ways in drawing a graph out of data points: Using [PGFPlots](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf) with

```
 \begin{axis}
 \addplot[smooth,color=red,mark=x]
```

or the Data Visualization inside [Tikz](http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) (p. 756 in the manual):

```
\datavisualization [school book axes, visualize as smooth line]
```

It seems that I could use both machnics for creating my easiy graphic, however is one approach much better or are both the same as they based both on tikz and just have different syntax? Which one is better for future compatibility or is more flexibel?

I just want to make an 2d axis with two graphs and 20 datapoints each, so just very basic things.

Comment: If you ask 3 users, you will get 7 opinions. None of them is strictly better. However, if you see yourself ever using 3D plots, then there might be a preference for `pgfplots`.

Comment: There are already question similar to yours. Have a look at e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/434916/95441, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/330932/95441, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66264/95441, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/198528/95441

Answer (score 1):

I use the operations described in section 22.2 "The Plot Path Operation", and those seem to work very well for me. As I'm already using TikZ for many other things, I find it easiest to stick with just one thing to learn.